# Designing for a specific flowrate

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pumps, heating-systems, fluid

I have a simple, practical engineering question.

I'm trying to design a hot water circulation system with a constant flow rate of 1.3 L/min. I'm having trouble finding any pumps that will do the job at the temperature (80-100C) for a reasonable cost.

Essentially, I'm trying to [Development of a Consistent and Reproducible Porcine Scald Burn Model](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0162888)

Does anyone know:

1. Where to search for for reliable, inexpensive, high-temperature water pumps? I tried McMaster Carr, but they didn't have anything that fit the bill.
2. Another way to adjust the flow rate? I thought a nozzle might work, but I'm worrying about too much back pressure damaging the pump, or worse, that a restricted area wouldn't even reduce the flow (RTT)?

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting/shopping question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Wasabi Sorry. Could you point me to an appropriate place to ask this question?

Comment: Grundfoss also make flow controllers as well as pumps...

Answer (score 4):

Many commercial hot water recirculation pumps will do that. Just grabbed one at random - Grundfoss Alpha1 15 40 130.

I couldn't fetch the page after I ran their calculator. I used temp of 99C and head of 2m. 100C doesn't work in their calculator. Click link then click "view in product center", and fill in form. [ALPHA1 circulator pump - heating, cooling, hot water](https://www.grundfos.com/products/find-product/alpha1.html)

You also have to edit settings for 60hz.